# Why Angular ViewEncapsulation enum has keys without value 1?

Tags: angular

When I checked source code of angular viewEncapsulation I saw enum without value with `1`. Why there are three options without element with 1?

[image: ViewEncapsulation enum]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/16.0.5/packages/core/src/metadata/view.ts

```
// Historically the 1 value was for `Native` encapsulation which has been removed as of v11.
```